# Repack PyInstaller exe after extracting

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Is it possible to repack/rebuild a PyInstaller exe file after extracting the files  from it using [PyInstaller Extractor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyinstallerextractor/)? I also decomplied most of the files with  [Easy Python Decomplier](https://sourceforge.net/projects/easypythondecompiler/). I modified one .py file and I want the new exe file to contain this modified file. How can I repack the application?

Comment: how about this problem now?

Answer (score 1):

You may leave all not modified files as `*.pyc`.

Once you have full modules structure ready, just find the original entrypoint and pack the bundle again, it should work.

Comment: So what I didn't write in my question is that I am totally new to Python. Can you give me some simpler instructions, or point me to some tutorials or documents?

Comment: I'm not sure there are any complete tutorials. Do you have any files that are named like "app", "main", application name etc? Find such file and execute `pyinstaller $ENTRYPOINT.py` command. `*.pyc` file will also work.